# Any ideas on how to resolve this conflicts error below?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, linux-kernel

I'm trying to install gcc4-4.1.2-44.EL4_8.1.i386.rpm on my redhat 5.x system but need a lot of dependencies.

```
dependency - kernel-headers-2.2.19-1.0.291.i386.rpm, installed okay
dependency - glibc-headers-2.8.90-11.i386.rpm, 
              [root@bruce glibc-headers]# rpm -ivh glibc* 
              error: Failed dependencies:
              glibc = 2.8.90-11 is needed by glibc-headers-2.8.90-11.i386
dependency - glibc-2.3.4-2.i386.rpm
              [root@bruce glibc]# rpm -ivh glibc*
              warning: glibc-2.3.4-2.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 73307de6 error: Failed dependencies:
              glibc-common = 2.3.4-2 is needed by glibc-2.3.4-2.i386
              glibc < 2.5 conflicts with glibc-common-2.5-18.i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you first try this with yum? yum would automagically fetch and install all dependencies.

```
yum update glibc
```

should do it for you. It does look like you're updating glibc because some other package depends on it. You could install that original package through yum (if it is available in a repository) and that would handle this and all subsequent dependencies.

```
yum install <your_original_sw_name>
```